# Remove conflict between Zopim chat and custombox when implemented simultaneously on a web page

Tags: javascript, zopim

I have to integrate Zopim chat and custombox together in my project. Html code for Zopim chat and custombox appears on same place of DOM tree i.e first child after body tag. The issue is when I open custombox it removes zopim chat box. Can anyone help me out. Thanks in advance.